# Bash script for sending emails to multiple recipients

Tags: bash

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Group1;Email address of group1;
Item1 of group1;
Item2 of group1;
Group2;Email address of group2;
Item1 of group2;
Item2 of group2;
Item3 of group2;
```

I want to write a bash script that sends emails like that:

```
To: email address of group(n)
Message: Item1 of group(n)
         Item2 of group(n)
```

I was told that I should use awk but I don't know how to combine a loop with awk so that it puts those items in the email body. There are ~150 groups.

Example input:

```
DC.EWS;alice.blue@company.com;
Hdfhjsf;
Ddshugds;
Sccbcbcjs;
Eweq-dhhda;
CCC.DGAA;bob.green@company.com;
Ssdf-sdhwq sdhaa;
Fdsjjew.sdhah;
Xsdjasdhdsf;
```

Example output:

Email to alice.blue@company.com:

```
Hi!  
Do you have the source for these items?     

Hdfhjsf  
Ddshugds  
Sccbcbcjs  
Eweq-dhhda  

Thanks.
```

Email to bob.green@company.com:

```
Hi!  
Do you have the source for these items?    

Ssdf-sdhwq sdhaa  
Fdsjjew.sdhah  
Xsdjasdhdsf  

Thanks.
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of some sample values and the _exact_ output needed?